# The Civic-Duty Badge

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges

Does anyone else feel that the Civic Duty badge just gives noobs an excuse to upvote like hell. I know I did it just to get my first silver badge and it didn't take surprisingly long.

Comment: +1 (getting closer to CD badge..)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I was upvoting anything I considered to be good before I knew about the Civic Duty badge. I think the ease of upvoting encourages upvoting more than the badge. And I think it's a good thing.

Answer (score 22):

Upvote? Yeah, that's one option...

Point is, it encourages folks to vote. And voting is essential to the operation of SO.

Answer (score 13):

Also there is a daily upvote limitation (I suppose the limit is 30 upvote per day), this prevents the misusage of the voting system I think.

Comment: It's 30 per day on comments, and 40 upvotes total per day(as of september 2012)

Answer (score 8):

I have never purposely done anything to get a badge, other than post good answers.

Comment: Your a good person. That rare on the internet. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It took me months to get it, I was aware it was there but never really tried for it. It's a badge that comes natually with use of the site.

Comment: yea kinda same here, I'm close to getting it now, and because of that, when I see a good question i don't hesitate too much before the upvote.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it could but with the upvote limit per day, and with the hope that they will at least upvote good answers, not just the random ones, it might be a good thing.

Plus after they get their Civic Duty badge, they might be more prone to upvoting good answers compared to others users...